# What is the correct way to resolve the namespace prefixed handle for an apex:chart?

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, charts, namespace, visualforce-charting

The nearest parallel is RemoteAction methods. The difficulty is that it appears two ways in JavaScript:

- In a **development org**, the function is just available as `MyController.getData`
- In a **managed package**, the function is available as `ns.MyController.getData`

Of course, the above is resolved using the `$RemoteAction` global to fully qualify as appropriate.

---

**My problem is with `<apex:chart name="Graph" />`** which generates a `Graph` JavaScript object:

- In a **development org**, the objects are available as `Graph` and `GraphModel`
- In a **managed package**, the objects must be accessed `ns.Graph` and `ns.GraphModel`

What is *the correct way* to resolve the fully qualified name for charts appearing on packaged pages?

> http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_chart.htm

Answer (score 3):

In the past I have used custom settings for exactly this sort of problem. Disclaimer: I haven't tested this against Apex:Chart tags but assume it will work !

The solution consists of the following:

1. Create custom setting with a attribute to store the namespace value
2. In your controller, fetch the value for the namespace (in dev it will be blank but in your managed package org this will be ns)
3. In your VF page, bind the apex chart name attribute to the variable in your controller

This will get you to a stage where it should work in both orgs, provided the data is present.

1. Create / modify your post install helper script to set this value automatically on install of the package in any org to the namespace of your package.